# PHP refresh window? equivalent to F5 page reload?

Tags: php, refresh, reload

Is there anything in PHP that is the equivalent of manually pressing the F5 page reload button?  My php script is in a frame and isn't the parent script but it needs to refresh the entire page and not just it's frame.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With PHP you just can handle server-side stuff. What you can do is print this in your iframe:

```
parent.window.location.reload();
```

Comment: . . . a further question. I did: echo "<body onload=\"parent.window.location.reload()\">"; which reloads the entire page which is just I need, but the frame in which the executing php script was in, is not updating.  And I can't seem to call another parent.window.location.reload or even a onload=\"window.location='$page'\"  what can I do?

Comment: not sure I got it, but have you checked your frame src? Check if parent.window is loading it correctly...

Comment: I checked the frame source, and it's correct.  But the frame is not loading correctly on parent.window.location.reload().  Not sure why.  How can I check that parent.window is loading it correctly?

Comment: `parent.window.location.reload()` will reload the current page whatever it is. You have to check your `parent.window.location.href` source code =)

Comment: it seems I can't reload the frame and whole page at the same time.

Comment: but I found a work around.  After the entire page reloads, I then go in just change the frame.  It works.  Thanks for help once again!!!

Answer (score 29):

Actually it is possible:

```
Header('Location: '.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
Exit(); //optional
```

And it will reload the same page.

Comment: This one should be marked as approved because it does exactly what's intended in php (no javascript or insertion into HTML).

Comment: @Ryuji This does NOT solve the original question.  How would this cause the parent document to reload?

Comment: @MikeBrant because that is exactly what it does. It orders php to reload the same page.

Comment: @NewProger You do realize that this would result in an infinite redirect? Also you realize that the original question was about reloading a parent window from a child window, which this does absolutely nothing to solve. Just because the OP asked for a PHP solution, doesn't mean there is one.

Answer (score 7):

If you have any text before a

```
header('Location: http://www.example.com/youformhere.php');
```

you'll have issues, because that must be sent before any other text is sent to the page.

Try using this code instead

```
<?php 
$page = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
echo '<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0;' . $page . '">';
?>
```

Just remember, this code will create and infinite loop, so you'll probably need to make some conditional changes to it.

Answer (score 5):

PHP cannot force the client to do anything. It cannot refresh the page, let alone refresh the parent of a frame.

EDIT: You can of course, make PHP write JavaScript, but this is not PHP doing, it's actually JavaScript, and it will fail if JavaScript is disabled.

```
<?php
    echo '<script>parent.window.location.reload(true);</script>';
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 
echo "<script>window.opener.location.reload();</script>";
echo "<script>window.close();</script>";
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

with php you can use two redirections.
It works same as refresh in some issues.

you can use a page redirect.php and post your last url to it by GET method (for example).
then in redirect.php you can change header to location you`ve sent to it by GET method.

like this:
your page:

```
<?php
header("location:redirec.php?ref=".$your_url);
?>
```

redirect.php:

```
<?php
$ref_url=$_GET["ref"];
header("location:redirec.php?ref=".$ref_url);
?>
```

that worked for me good.

Answer (score 0):

Use JavaScript for this. You can do:

```
echo '
<script type="text/javascript">
   parent.window.location.reload(true);
</script>
';
```

In PHP and it will refresh the parent's frame page.

Answer (score 0):

guess you could echo the meta tag to do the refresh in regular intervals ... like

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="600" url="your-url-here">
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do to manually refresh a page is to provide a link pointing to the same page

Like this:
Refresh the selection

Answer (score -2):

Adding following in the page header works for me:

```
<?php

if($i_wanna_reload_the_full_page_on_top == "yes")
{
$reloadneeded = "1";
}
else
{
$reloadneeded = "0";
}

if($reloadneeded > 0)
{
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
top.window.location='indexframes.php';
</script>
<?php
}else{}
?>
```